# Do Virtual Photons Travel with the Speed of Light?

Tags: particle-physics, speed-of-light, virtual-particles

The question is in the title. When we consider Feynman-diagrams (e. g. $e^{+}e^{-} \rightarrow\mu^{+}\mu^{-}$), we often have virtual photons. Do these travel with the speed of light?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are virtual particles limited by the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147825/)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/117013